# Scatter plot best fit line error in R - Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv())

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot a simple best fit line to a scatterplot.

this example works:

```
plot(dist ~ speed, data= cars, xlab="Speed", ylab="Distance", col= "blue")
title(main="Scatter plot with best-fit line", font.main= 4)
abline(lm(dist ~ speed, data= cars), col= "red")
```

however with my data I get an error message:

```
plot(log(datatest$MEAN_intact_for),log(datatest$ERmammal_0_1), col= "blue")
title(main="Scatter plot with best-fit line", font.main= 4)
abline(lm(log(datatest$ERmammal_0_1)~log(datatest$MEAN_intact_for)), col= "red")
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

I have tried searching it but I am new to R and so if anyone can give me any simple advice on this that would be great.
- when I just plot the graph it works fine, the problem is when I add the abline command to get a best fit line. 
I also tried

Hopefully someone can help. Apologies if its really obvious.

Answer (score 1):

When you use abline() you need to input the intercept (a) and slope (b) as parameters, rather than just sticking the lm() in there. So let's say:

```
fmla = lm(log(datatest$ERmammal_0_1)~log(datatest$MEAN_intact_for))
```

then you want:

```
abline(a = fmla$coefficients[1], b = fmla$coefficients[2])
```